# The set of tautologies is decidable

Tags: logic, decidability

> the set of taulologies is decidable. In other words, the set
>   $$ \text{TAUTOLOGY}=\{\text{Gö}(\varphi)\mid \varphi \text{ is a tautology}\}$$
>   is recursive.

I would try to prove so, showing that the set and its complement are recursively enumerable.

**My attemp**

1. I would start by constructing a finite list of basis tautologies, then showing that all other tautologies can be deduced from this finite set using Modus Ponen. I'm reading  Yu.I.Manin 'A course in mathematical logic' to do so, and working on a complete clean proof, but this is quite long.
2. Then I need to show that the set of basis tautologies is recursively enumerable. The proof I'm writin is also very long. I need first to proove that the set of Axioms and the set of formulas is decidable.
3. Finally, I need to show that the complement of the set is recursively enumerable. I don't know how to do so.

Does anyone knows a good reference for this proof? I would like to understand this full process. If there exists a grood proof of this statement I would love to read it.

I know that the proof could also consists of a reformulation of the condition $n \in$ TAUTOLOGY constructed from formulas expressing membership to recursive sets an relations by means of Boolean connectives and bounded quantication. If the proof follows this path this is fine for me too.

Comment: Basic truth-table method is a decision procedure for tautologueness.

Comment: Yes, I know that for a given formula, the truth table method will give me a decision to know if yes or no this is a tautology. But **(1)** this is provably correct, but how? **(2)** I would like to use some more general proposition of "decidability", in order to get used to the notions.

Comment: Is this propositional or first-order logic? Because the set of first-order tautologies is **not** decidable.

Comment: You know that for saying something is decidable, any program can be an example of a decision procedure?  After the set of tautologies is defined, the logic is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be talking about propositional logic since, as Noah points out in the comments, first-order logic is not decidable. And, as Mauro points out, truth-tables are a perfectly good method to decide whether a propositional logic statements is a tautology or not.

Now, you are asking for a proof as to why truth-tables are indeed such a decision procedure ... but that proof is simply this:  A tautology is defined as a statement that for each valuation (truth-assignment) evaluates to true. Well, truth-tables exhaustively explore all possible valuations. To be precise: each valuation will be captured by one of the rows of the truth-table. And, since working out the values in a truth-table corresponds exactly to following the formal semantics according to which valuations are being defined, the eventual truth-value you find in the truth-table is exactly what it should be for that valuation.  And finally, working out a truth-table takes a finite amount of time: since any statement in propositional logic is of finite length, there are finitely many propositional logic variables in any statement, and therefore you have a finite number of rows in the truth-table, and working out the truth-value of the statement for each row takes a finite number of steps, corresponding to the finite number of logical operations in the statement.

And so, if in a truth-table you find that the statement always evaluates to true (it takes finite time to check this) then you know that it evaluates to true for all possible valuations, and hence it is a tautology. On the other hand, if in at least one row it evaluates to false (again, you'll find this in finite time), then you know there is a valuation for which the statement is false, and hence the statement is not a tautology.

So yes, truth-tables are a perfectly good decision procedure.

Now, I know this is not *your* method ... so, what I say about that?  Well, first take a look at [Wikipedia's page for Propositional Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Alternative_calculus):

Here, they start to describe what you want: a set of axioms (all tautologies) which, together with the single inference rule Modus Ponens, allows you to prove other tautologies.  Now, you can prove that this set of axioms is complete (the same Wikipedia page has some discussion on completeness), in the sense that all tautologies can indeed be derived from the axioms and Modus Ponens. And that shows that the set of tautologies is recursively enumerable ... but not that the set of non-tautologies is enumerable ... and thus, as you realize, you don't have a decision procedure yet.

Indeed, using formal proofs you can only demonstrate that statements are tautologies, but not that statements are not tautologies (unless the statement happens to be a contradiction, in which case demonstrating (i.e. proving) its negation to be a tautology tells you that the original is not a tautology).

Given this limitation of proof methods it is indeed not at all clear how you would extend that into a decision procedure ... which is exactly why Mauro and I suggest a truth-table method, which can demonstrate *both* tautologies to be tautologies, *and* non-tautologies to be non-tautologies,

Now, there are some other methods, though, and one I really like is the [semantic tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux) or truth-tree method. This method tries to figure out whether some statement (or set of statements) is satisfiable (i.e. can be made true), and you can show that for propositional logic, this method is in fact a decision procedure for exactly that: if the statement is not satisfiable, then the tableaux will eventually lead to all closed branches, and if it is satisfiable, then the tableaux is guaranteed to lead to at least one open branch (not an easy proof, but not crazy hard either). So, if you have a statement and want to know whether or not it is a tautology, you simply negate the statement, and use the tableaux method to figure out if that negation is satisfiable: if it is, then the original statement is not a tautology, and if it is not, then the original statement is a tautology. Hence, this is a decision procedure for propositional logic.

What's also cool about this method is that, unlike truth-tables, it is a method that you can use for fist-order logic ... though it is no longer a decision procedure for first-order logic, since you can get infinite-length trees. Indeed, as Turing showed, there simply cannot be any decision procedure for first-order logic.

Comment: There also exists a proof search based decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional logic - whereas as far as I know, there is no "nice" description of the free Heyting algebra on two or more variables.  (Whereas in the case of Boolean algebras, the free Boolean algebra on $n$ variables is isomorphic to $P(P([n]))$, which can be interpreted as the set of possible truth tables.)

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, some restrictions of first-order logic are still decidable, such as if you forbid any function or predicate symbols in the signature.  But the decision procedures I can think of in such cases would be based on some form of quantifier elimination or automated proof search, and truth tables would be insufficient without major adjustments.

Comment: Amazing complete answer. Thanks!!

Comment: I've looked at propositional logic, and first-order. I'm not looking at arithmetic, in particular $(\mathbb{N}; 0;S;<;+;\cdot)$. I will make a new question, because this would be quite different i think